# How to combine glob and pd.read_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to get a CSV into a dataframe using using `pd.read_csv` however the csv that I'm loading changes its filename daily (hence why i'm using glob)

This is what i have so far but its spiting out a error `Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>`

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
csv_load = pd.read_csv(glob.glob(r'C:\Users\mc\pythonprojects\csvconversion\*.csv'))
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\mc\pythonprojects\csvconversion\*.csv')])
```

or if you are sure that there is one file :

```
csv_load = pd.read_csv(glob.glob(r'C:\Users\mc\pythonprojects\csvconversion\*.csv')[0])
```

Explanation: golb.glob return a list, so you should choose element from this list